# Flashcam doesn't compile -- videodev.h not found

Tags: lubuntu, compiling

I'd like to compile Flashcam 1.4.5 from source on Lubuntu 13.04, but it complains:

```
cc -g -shared -fPIC -o flashcamhook.so flashcamhook.c
flashcamhook.c:31:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
```

I have linux-headers-generic installed along with the headers for my current kernel (3.8.0-23-generic).
I have installed libv4l-0,libv4lconvert0 and libv4l-dev.
Build-essentials is installed.

I tried sym-linking (with absolute paths) videodev.h to libv4l1-videodev.h, then to videodev2.h, but this doesn't help either.

Working directory is /tmp/flashcam-1.4.5 .

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Comment: What directories are you doing this in?  Have you linked with absolute paths?

Comment: I'm working in /tmp. When linking, I used absolute paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its not possible to find `videodev.h` because it has been replaced with `videodev2.h`. More info, [here](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/vloopback-help-202968252.html#202968262)

On my machine, I see this

```
/usr/src$ find . -name videodev*
./linux-headers-3.8.0-19/include/linux/videodev2.h
./linux-headers-3.8.0-19/include/uapi/linux/videodev2.h
./linux-headers-3.8.0-23/include/linux/videodev2.h
./linux-headers-3.8.0-23/include/uapi/linux/videodev2.h
./linux-headers-3.8.0-21/include/linux/videodev2.h
./linux-headers-3.8.0-21/include/uapi/linux/videodev2.h
./linux-headers-3.8.0-22-generic/include/linux/videodev2.h
./linux-headers-3.8.0-23-generic/include/linux/videodev2.h
./linux-headers-3.8.0-21-generic/include/linux/videodev2.h
./linux-headers-3.8.0-22/include/linux/videodev2.h
./linux-headers-3.8.0-22/include/uapi/linux/videodev2.h
./linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/include/linux/videodev2.h
/usr/src$
```